# Good Silverlight 4.0 chart / graph component?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts, graphing

I've been using the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) but I'm finding the quality lacking; in particular [this memory leak / phantom point bug](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=2677) renders the Chart component completely unusable.

Can anyone recommend a good chart / graph component for Silverlight 4.0?  I'm looking for one that provides:

- multiple simultaneous series, both scatter and line
- multi-select of points
- configurable tool-tips
- automatic axis scaling
- real-time update of data

That last point sounds trivial but is tripping up the Silverlight Toolkit Chart; if you rapidly change the axis range, it sometimes leaves phantom points behind in addition to the points it *should* be displaying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/). It supports all the above requested features.

[image]

Comment: It works fine. I use it too. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Visiblox](http://www.visiblox.com).
<sub>(Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops it, but not on that team)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the Data Visualization suite offered by Infragistics.  I'm not really a big fan of Infragistics but I have been impressed with some of their charting components.

http://samples.infragistics.com/sldv/ComponentOverview.aspx?cn=data-chart